# C++ Object Design issue: efficiently and safely construct objects and save/load with database

Tags: c++, object

my English is not good enough to explain my problem. But I will try my best.

I used to be a Java programmer but have been using C++ more than a year. The one thing always bothers me is the strategy of creating business objects from network(like through SNMP, Web Service or other data sources...) and save it to database and load it when application startup. Usually my design is like following :

```
class Object{
/* this is just a demonstration, in real code, there are all kinds of Object and has relationships*/
friend class DBConnection;
friend class SNMPConn
private:
    std::string& m_strName; 
    //... all kinds of properties
}

class DBConnection
{
   int load(Object& obj);
   int save(Object& obj);
   int modify(Object& obj);
   int loadAll(std::vector);
}

class SNMPConn
{
   int load(Object& obj);
   ...
}
```

The thing I am not conmforable with is the line of "friend class ..." . It breaks the encapsulation.I found some framework, like litesql(sourceforge.net/apps/trac/litesql) and other commercial ones, but these frameworks are difficult to integrate with my existing code. I am trying to do it manually and trying to find a common strategy for this kind of work.

I was a Java deveoper, design in C++ is the thing I'm not good at. I don't know what's the best practice for this kind of design work.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand from this problem (breaking encapsulation during reading and writing to DB or SNMP connection), first you need a proper design to eliminate these "friend"s. please define an abstract class for connections (i.e. IDBConnection) also persistent objects (i.e. IPersistent). You may use "Abstract Factory" pattern to create them. Furthermore, isolate load and save methods to another class and use "visitor pattern" to initialize or save your objects from/to your DB.

Another point, if you need an embedded DB for your application, use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) there are tons of good C++ wrappers for it. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I might do it in pseudo-code:

```
class Result { 
public: 
    int     getField(name); 
    string  getField(name); 
}

class Connection { 
public: 
    void save(list<pair<string, string>> properties); 
    Result query(); 
} 

class DBConnection { 
private: 
    class DBResult : public Result {  
    } 
public: 
    Result query() { 
        return ( DBResult ); 
    } 
    void save
}

class Object { 
public: 
    void load(Result); 
    void save(Connection) { 
        // make properties list 
        connection.save(properties); 
    } 
}
```

Without Java-style reflection, that's probably how I'd do it without getting into "friend"-ship relationships.  Then you're not tightly coupling the knowledge of connection logic into the connection classes.

...

You could also build template functions to do it, but you'd still need a friend relationship.

```
class Object { 
public: 
    friend template<class Conn, class Obj> load(Conn c, Obj o);
    friend template<class Conn, class Obj> save(Conn c, Obj o);
} 

load<Connection, Object>(Connection c, Object o) { 
    //access o.private to load into c 
}
```

I'm not sure which way I'd go.  In one respect, you encapsulate load/save logic in your Object classes, which is great for locality, but it might tightly couple your persistence and business logic all in one location.